# Compare rows in one table - depends on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have two columns in my table, `Project` column and `configuration` column.
the `configuration` column is concatenating of 3 columns separated by "_".
i need to select for every project only the columns that different only in this project.

i don't know how many projects there are,and for every project the unique column is different.
for example this the table i have:

[image]

as you can see the different columns in project 1 is column 1 and 3.
in project 2 is column 3, and in project 4 is column 2.
i want to get in my query for every row only the columns that are different in this project

Comment: Storing data in relational DB as "separated lists" is a bad idea almost everytime. Use separate table and one-to-many relations instead and your task will be significantly simpler.

Comment: You really should consider normailizing your database.

Comment: I seem it's just approximate example, isn't it?

Comment: it's not up to me, but i'm trying to normalize my DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that you simply have no choice but to work with the data you posted (like it was just handed to you and you have no recourse but to make-do)

You can try this:

```
-- Declare the variable for usage later
DECLARE @Project INT
SET @Project = 1

-- Let's use a temp table, say #t2
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t2') is  null
BEGIN
    -- Just trying: Split the Configuration string since
    --   it would appear the positions are in place
    --   at least in your example
    SELECT * INTO #t2 FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, Substring(Configuration, 1, 2) AS Col1
        , Substring(Configuration, 4, 2) AS Col2
        , Substring(Configuration, 7, 2) AS Col3
    FROM yourTable --Replace with your table name
    WHERE Project = @Project -- Variable in use here
    GROUP BY Substring(Configuration, 1, 2) 
        , Substring(Configuration, 4, 2) 
        , Substring(Configuration, 7, 2) 
    ) t1
END

-- End select to show the project and the columns that are different
SELECT DISTINCT @Project AS Project, LEFT(REPLACE(Col1, 'A', 1),1) AS DiffColumnNum FROM #t2 GROUP BY Col1 
    HAVING  (COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t2)) -- Weird having clause :)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT @Project AS Project, LEFT(REPLACE(Col2, 'B', 2),1) AS DiffColumnNum FROM #t2 GROUP BY Col2 
    HAVING  (COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t2))
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT @Project AS Project, LEFT(REPLACE(Col3, 'C', 3),1) AS DiffColumnNum FROM #t2 GROUP BY Col3 
    HAVING  (COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t2))
```

I agree with the comments in your question area; best to normalize but if you have no say in the matter, try this code. It isn't optimized, I know, but it might do the trick.

Comment: Sorry; I hope you didn't have to make too many changes.. but I'm glad it works for you now